# Any design pattern can replace promise/then chain in javascript?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

Now I am using Promise/then to design my code(part of code in class) like below:

```
Condition.getFromServer()
.then(ContentInfoFromServer =>
    this.foo(para)
)
.then(para =>
    this.bar(para)
)
.then(para =>
    this.jor(para)
)
.then(para =>
    this.dom(para)
)
.then(para =>
    this.pam(para)
)
```

But I think it is not very good for performance. So I want find something replace this code, I've tried the chain of responsibility. But it seems like so heavy for this. 
Could you please suggest some good way to replace that. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you think this yields bad performance?

Comment: @RaduDiță  Because I think each '.then' will go to next eventloop.  And also It doesn't recommend write sync code like this.

Comment: You shouldn't write sync code like this. You should return a promise when you have async work. If your async work can be done in parallel you can use Promise.all.

Comment: Yes, already returned in the encapsulate function